# How replace all dots AFTER other chars got captured

Tags: regular-expression, perl, rename

I'm trying to rename some shows with the `perl-rename` command.
The format currently looks something like this:

```
series.S01E**.title.of.the.episode.mkv
```

The asterisks are place holders for the episode number.

I want to rename it like so:

```
[Series] - S01E** - title of the episode.mkv
```

I've managed to capture the name of the series as well as the episode, but i don't know how to replace the dots after i already matched something.

```
perl-rename 's/(\w+)\.(S\d{2}E\d{2})\./[\u$1] - $2 - /' -n *.mkv
                                     ^ No idea what to insert here
```

One call of `rename` is my goal.
The title may be any variable number of words long, so i cannot do something like `(\w+)\.(\w+).../$1 $2... # match a word and a dot` for a fixed amount of times.

What I'm looking for is basically a loop to match a pattern of `word.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
perl-rename -n 's{(\w+)\.(S\d{2}E\d{2})\.(.*)(\.mkv)\Z}{
  "[\u$1] - $2 - " . ($3 =~ y/./ /r) . $4}es' ./*.mkv
```

- `perl`-based `rename` implementations (all derived from [the `rename` example script](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/perl-3.000/eg/rename) that had been shipped with `perl` from as far back as perl 3 in 1989), rename the files given as arguments to the value of `$_` after it has been modified by the `perl` code given in the first argument.
- `s{regex}{replacement}flags`, same as `s/regex/replacement/flags` is short for `$_ =~ s{regex}{replacement}flag`. That is, the substitution operator is applied to the `$_` variable which contains the name the file is to be renamed to.
- Here *flags* contains `e` which means the replacement is interpreted as perl code which is `e`valuated to generate the replacement.
- We also use the `s` flag which causes `.` to also match the newline character which you generally want to use with `rename` as newline is as valid a character as any in a file name. It's also why we use `\Z` (matches at  the end of the subject) instead of `$` which in `perl` matches at the end of the subject but also possibly before a newline that is at the end of the subject. In this case though, it won't make a difference as all the file names end in `v`, not newline.
- `($3 =~ y/./ /r)` applies the `y` (aka `tr`) operator to the third capture group. With the `r` flag, the substitution is not applied in place (`$3` is read-only anyway), but the result of the substitution is `r`eturned instead.

Personally, I'd use `zsh`'s `zmv` instead:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv -n '(*).(S<1-99>E<1-99>).(*)(.mkv)' '[${(C)1}] - $2 - ${3//./ }$4'
```

Where `${(C)1}` capitalises every word (sequences of alnums) in the part before `./SXXEYY` (changes `foo.Bar-BAZ` to `Foo.Bar-Baz` for instance).

Advantages over `rename`:

- there's only one implementation (whilst there are dozens of variants of `rename`).
- it does some sanity checks before doing any renaming (for instance would abort if you had both a `series.S01E01.title x.mkv` and `Serias.S01E01.title.x.mkv`)
- doesn't have the arbitrary command injection vulnerabilities of some variants of perl `rename` if you forget the `--` (not supported by all) or `./` prefix.
- It also works with non-ASCII file names (like for `épisode` capitalised to `Épisode`).

Comment: I came across zmv before but i try to put all that in a script which may or may not be run by zsh.

Comment: Can you please explain what is happening? i have never seen the use of braces instead of slashes and the use of quotes. ($3 =~ seems like a sub command to replace dots with spaces

Comment: @Zacky, see edit.

Answer (score 0):

Just as with a `sed` or `perl` script, you can have more than one statement (either separated by `;`, or by using multiple `-e` options) in a perl `rename` script.  For example:

```
$ touch 'my.series.name.S01E'{01..03}'.title.of.the.episode.mkv'
$ ls -l
total 6
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas   0 Jun  7 10:56 my.series.name.S01E01.title.of.the.episode.mkv
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas   0 Jun  7 10:56 my.series.name.S01E02.title.of.the.episode.mkv
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas   0 Jun  7 10:56 my.series.name.S01E03.title.of.the.episode.mkv

$ rename 's/\./ /g; s/ (mkv)$/.$1/; s/^(.*) (S\d\dE\d\d) /[\u$1] - $2 - /' *.mkv
$ ls -l
total 6
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas   0 Jun  7 10:57 [My series name] - S01E01 - title of the episode.mkv
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas   0 Jun  7 10:57 [My series name] - S01E02 - title of the episode.mkv
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas   0 Jun  7 10:57 [My series name] - S01E03 - title of the episode.mkv
```

The rename script:

- Replaces all `.` characters with a space (including the `.` before the mkv extension)
- Changes the space before the extension back to a `.`.  This only works for .mkv files at present, but it's easy enough to change this from `s/ (mkv)$/.$1/` to, e.g. `s/ (mkv|avi|mp4)$/.$1/` if you have videos in other container formats.

  If you needed to handle filenames with multiple "extensions", such as `.xyz.mp4`, that would be more work and it would be difficult to distinguish between words in the episode title and "extensions" unless the extensions were all known in advance.
- Reformats the series name and episode-number portions of the filename as `[Series] - SnnEnn -` .  The episode title and extension are left as they were after the previous two commands.

NOTE: if you write any other shell scripts working with these files, you will have to be careful to double-quote any variables containing the filenames as they all contain space, `[`, and `]` characters.   This isn't a big deal as you should be quoting your variables anyway.

BTW, the statements in a `rename` script can be any valid perl code, and you can even `use` any perl module(s) you have installed.  Not all of the statements have to directly change the filename (e.g. you can have code that increments a counter, or runs `stat` on the filename to check its size or timestamp, or whatever - even query a database or make a web API call to discover the episode's title if it's missing from the filename).  Anything that changes `$_` will change the filename.

Comment: Not all `rename` variants support a `-e`. With those that do, you need a `--` or to use `./*.mkv` instead of `*.mkv` or running that on a directory that contains a file named `--e='system"reboot"#.mkv'` for instance would have severe consequences.

Comment: While there are lots of obsolete versions floating around, the only one that actually matters - the one from the [File::Rename](https://metacpan.org/release/File-Rename) perl module does support `-e`.   Current version is 1.31 (This is also the version in the current debian `rename` package).  And it's a given that users should take steps to protect themselves from bad or malicious filenames, especially when working in directories they don't control 100% or know completely.

Comment: See also the more feature-rich https://github.com/ap/rename. I've seen Q&As here where that one was the one available to the OP so it could be the one shipped with some distributions.

Comment: And also https://metacpan.org/release/PEDERST/rename-1.11 aka http://search.cpan.org/dist/rename/ used by https://archlinux.org/packages/community/any/perl-rename/ for instance with yet another API.

Comment: Also used by https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/prename-1.9-5.el7.noarch.rpm.html or https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/dev-perl/rename

Comment: That's nice, but i have not the time nor any desire to account for every possible obsolete or alternative version or weird, idiosyncratic fork of rename.

Comment: That works as well and is a lot more readable :)